# Javascript replace same items with different string by position

Tags: javascript, replace

I have some problem need to be replaced.

There is the **paragraph** like:

```
(*#*) <p>The video was posted on Facebook and shows a shirtless man repeatedly throwing rocks at a wombat as it tries to (*#*) run away.</p>
```

The symbol `(*#*)` is a position which need to be replace new string.

But the replacements are different, there will be the image, link and so on...

```
let photo = '<div class="photo"><img src="'+media+'"></div>'
let link = '<a class="relatednews" href="'+linkStr+'">'linkName'</a>'
```

The replacements are in order store by json, and I need to use them to replace the **paragraph** like:

```
<div class="photo"><img src="'+media+'"></div>
<p>The video was posted on Facebook and shows a shirtless man repeatedly throwing rocks at a wombat as it tries to <a class="relatednews" href="'+linkStr+'">'linkName'</a>' run away.</p>
```

I use the **for** and **replaceAt** could not handle this.

`replaceIndexAry` is store the position of `(*#*)`.

```
console.log(replaceIndexAry)
//[ 0 , 118 ] it's store the every (*#*) index in the paragraph;

for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){
      if(itype === 'photo'){
         mediaStr = self.replaceAt(paragraph,replaceIndexAry[j],photo)
      }else if(itype === 'link'){
         mediaStr = self.replaceAt(paragraph,replaceIndexAry[j],link)
      }
}

function replaceAt( origin, index, replacement){
    return origin.substr(0, index) + replacement+ origin.substr(index + replacement.length);
}
```

The result would be :

```
(*#*) <p>The video was posted on Facebook and shows a shirtless man repeatedly throwing rocks at a wombat as it tries to <a class="relatednews" href="'+linkStr+'">'linkName'</a>' run away.</p>
```

I could not replace all items successfully, how could I do to replace all `(*#*)` in **paragraph** with in order replacement data?

> p.s. The all data( include paragraph and replacement) are given by
>   Back-end, the API could not be changed, and the Back-end asked me follow
>   this logic.

Comment: From your example, why does the first `(*#*)` result in the `photo` replacement, and the second `(*#*)` result in the `link` replacement? (eg, why not the other way around, or have both replacements replace with the photo, etc?) Replacing them isn't hard, but I'm trying to figure out the logic you wish to implement

Comment: An example of a full `replaceIndexAry` object and the before/after string might help a lot

Comment: Because the all data( include paragraph and replacement) are given by Back-end, the API can not change, and the Back-end asked me follow this logic .

Comment: Without a better example, I'm not sure what the desired logic is, so I'm unable to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let data='(*#*) <p>The video was posted on Facebook and shows a shirtless man repeatedly throwing rocks at a wombat as it tries to (*#*) run away.</p>';

let photo = '<div class="photo"><img src="media"></div>';
let link = '<a class="relatednews" href="linkStr">linkName</a>';

data = data.replace('(*#*)', photo);
data = data.replace('(*#*)', link);
```

It will give you:

```
"<div class=\"photo\"><img src=\"media\"></div> <p>The video was posted on Facebook and shows a shirtless man repeatedly throwing rocks at a wombat as it tries to <a class=\"relatednews\" href=\"linkStr\">linkName</a> run away.</p>"
```

in **data** variable if I correctly understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you can do like this:

```
const str = "(*#*) <p>The video was posted on Facebook and shows a shirtless man repeatedly throwing rocks at a wombat as it tries to (*#*) run away.</p>";

const first_str = `<div class="photo"><img src="'+media+'"></div>`;
const second_str = `<a class="relatednews" href="'+linkStr+'">'linkName'</a>`;

const regex = /(\(\*\#\*\))(.*?)(\(\*\#\*\))(.*)/;
const replacement = `${first_str}$2${second_str}$4`;

const result = str.replace(regex, replacement);

// <div class="photo"><img src="'+media+'"></div> <p>The video was posted on Facebook and shows a shirtless man repeatedly throwing rocks at a wombat as it tries to <a class="relatednews" href="'+linkStr+'">'linkName'</a> run away.</p>
```